# 3 Particle problem with a difference

Tags: kinematics, calculus

Please read this completely, it is not the typical question you expect. 
3 particles are at the corners of an equilateral triangle with side a. Assume that particle 1 is at (0,0), particle 2 is at (a,0) and particle 3 is at (a/2, sqrt(3)/2). They all start moving simultaneously with a velocity v constant in modulus, but with the first particle heading towards the second one, the second towards the third, and the third towards the first particle. The typical question is how soon will they meet? I can easily answer this question with symmetry and relative speed considerations (they meet at the centroid after a time 2a/3v). My question is a bit more complicated. Can we solve this without invoking symmetry and purely mathematically? Second, can we describe the velocity vector of particle 1 as a function of time t assuming it started at the origin? Third, can we describe the trajectory of particle 1 as a curve mathematically?

Comment: the answer is yes

Comment: Do you mean they all are directed toward the geometrical center of the triangle? "Directed towards [each] other means the velocity is co-linear with $\Delta \vec{r}$, and that's impossible in your geometry. One pair is okay, but the third one is left out of the idea.

Comment: Thanks, Bort. How does one begin to think about this problem? How does one relate the change of angle with the time t?

Comment: "assuming it started at the origin"  What origin? You have to define one.

Comment: @BillN, No. Each particle's velocity is directed towards the other at all times. That is, particle 1 is chasing particle 2, and particle 2 is chasing particle3 and particle 3 is chasing paricle 1. So, they do meet in the centroid of the triangle.

Comment: @BillN, Assume that particle 1 is at the origin (0,0). Particle 2 is at a distance a  on the x axis (a,0). Particle 3 is located at (a/2, sqrt(3)/2)

Comment: Edit you question to state that specifically.  You have 3 particles and they can't all chase each other, i.e., particle 1 can't chase both 2 and 3.  Your original setup is unclear, and making assumptions is dangerous.

Comment: @BillN, point taken. I've edited the question now to cite that specifically.

Comment: I believe you need to specify how are the particles attracted to each other (e.g., spring-like force, coulomb-like force, etc.).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, this is a purely kinematics problem, or at least I think it is. There is no need to understand the forces at play since we are just interested in the motion of the particles and not in why they are moving.

Comment: you dont need to know $F$ to say **where** they'll meet, but you do need to know $F$ to calculate the **time** it'll take for them to, for example (you say that $T=2a/3v$, but what is $v$? the velocity might change in time, depending on what $F$ is). Also, they'll meet at the centre of the triangle if and only if the force is central. A short script in your favourite programming language might convince you that the motion depends on the explicit form of $F$.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, as described in the statement, v is the constant modulus of the velocity vector of each of the particles and T=2a/3v uses this magnitude of velocity. That modulus doesn't change in time. Only the direction of the velocity vector of each particle changes as described in the question (due to each particle being directed towards the other). Sure, there may be a force that is doing this to them. But, I'm only interested in describing the motion. Sure, the direction of velocity is changing with time even if the magnitude is not changing.

Comment: If you want a purely mathematical answer(with symmetry/vectors)...then maybe math stackexchange can help you more...